# Getting Always 1.0 with a Simple NDCG Java Example

Tags: java, information-retrieval

As you may know, the NDCG is a nice ranking metric. I am trying to use it to get a performance value of two list below:

list1-->{2, 5, 6, 8, 3}-->this is the ranked list

list2--> {2, 6, 5, 8, 3}-->this is the correct list

Assume the numbers as the ids of elements

Here is the Java Code:

```
//{2, 5, 6, 8, 3};
    List<Integer> rankedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    rankedList.add(2);
    rankedList.add(5);
    rankedList.add(6);
    rankedList.add(8);
    rankedList.add(3);

    //{2, 6, 5, 8, 3}
    List<Integer> correctList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    correctList.add(2);
    correctList.add(6);
    correctList.add(5);
    correctList.add(8);
    correctList.add(3);
    double ndcgVal = NDCG.compute(rankedList, correctList, null);
    System.out.println("NDCG Value: " + ndcgVal);
```

Source: https://github.com/jcnewell/MyMediaLiteJava/blob/master/src/org/mymedialite/eval/measures/NDCG.java

```
package org.fatih.networkpatternsui;

import java.util.Collection;

import java.util.HashSet;

import java.util.List;

public class NDCG {

// Prevent instantiation.
private NDCG() {}
public static double compute(
  List<Integer> ranked_items,
  Collection<Integer> correct_items,
  Collection<Integer> ignore_items) {

if (ignore_items == null)
  ignore_items = new HashSet<Integer>();

double dcg = 0;
double idcg = computeIDCG(correct_items.size());
int left_out = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < ranked_items.size(); i++) {
  int item_id = ranked_items.get(i);
  if (ignore_items.contains(item_id)) {
    left_out++;
    continue;
  }

  if (!correct_items.contains(item_id))
    continue;

  // compute NDCG part
  int rank = i + 1 - left_out;
  dcg += Math.log(2) / Math.log(rank + 1);

}

return dcg / idcg;
static double computeIDCG(int n)
{
double idcg = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  idcg += Math.log(2) / Math.log(i + 2);
return idcg;
}
}
```

The problem here is that I always get the value as 1.0

Could you help me with that please?

Answer (score 4):

Since relevance seems to be binary, and all the relevant documents are also retrieved, 1.0 is the correct value: there is no gain (or loss) in ranking document 5 before/after document 6.

Try to include non-relevant documents in your ranked list (i.e. document ids which are not correct) and you should see the difference. In particular, try different positions for the non-relevant document, to observe what the log(rank) does.

If you consider graded relevance and include relevance score in your code, assuming document 6 has a higher relevance than document 5 (i.e. a higher relevance score), the rankedList will be sub-optimal and hence will have ndcg<1.0